# zen coding and abreviation are not working in vs code

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, emmet

well, I've changed my laptop and I find out that vs code in my new laptop isn't working like the old one.

- the first problem is zen coding isn't working, I tried to lock for an extension but I didn't find any.
- the second problem is I can't find the abbreviation, they aren't working to, 've tried to install HTML Snippets and HTML CSS support extensions, I tried to sync my setting from the old laptop with vs code account, nothing worked and I am running out of options

Hers an example, this abbreviation used to give me the HTML base code, even '!' doesn't give me anything. [image]

Comment: Are you looking for [Emmet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet)?

Comment: @RichardDeeming yes I think so!

Comment: @RichardDeeming IDK why, but it's not working